# How many character see in the log in android

Tags: android

can any body tell how many caharacter we can seen in the log file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation on the [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class does not mention any limitations on the log message length. So generally it should be ok to output messages of any length.

Though there is an inconvenience: the LogCat of Eclipse ADT plugin poorly handles long lines. However you always can do "adb logcat" in console to read your logs.